# Objectify Transactions using VoidWork

Tags: java, gwt, transactions, objectify

I am using Objectify version 4. I want to use transactions in my project. Project is based on GWT Java and objectify. As per objectify tutorials i found that ofy().transact() method to be used. So i preferred to use the following

ofy().transact(new VoidWork() {
    public void vrun() {
         Here i wrote code for saving data to entity
    }
});

When i execute the project on development server/local i get a error message stating that

No source code is available for type com.googlecode.objectify.VoidWork; did you forget to inherit a required module?

The method createBillingDocs() is undefined for the type new VoidWork(){}

createBillingDocs is my method which i want to execute in transaction.

So any help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't run transactions or use Objectify client-side; it is a server-side framework for accessing the datastore. You need to separate out your client-side logic from your server-side logic and define your GWT modules carefully.